# MYSQL Group Sales by Week

Tags: mysql, date, grouping

I have a MYSQL table called `orders`
Each row has (amongst other things) an `order_date` which is formatted in timestamp value (EX: `2022-02-25 19:45:22`) and total (as a float EX: `25.65`)

I'd like to group the sales by the last full 13 weeks...
I expect output such as this:

```
"Week of:  2022-03-13" : "3455.23"

"Week of:  2022-03-20" : "2544.85"

"Week of:  2022-03-27" : "4125.55"
```

OR

```
"2022 FW 12" : "3455.23"

"2022 FW 13" : "2544.85"

"2022 FW 14" : "4125.55"
```

on and on up until the last final week with a total of 13 results.
I know how to do this with just one week, but I am looking for a better answer than running 13 queries.

Comment: Just a concern, what is the basis of you "Week of".  Some people use Sunday, others Monday, and accommodating a possible day shift due to YOUR week start could have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the WEEK function in mySQL to extract the week from a date.You can then do your totals grouped by this year/rank

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I need a working example, I do not know how to implement this

Comment: this is not a place where we do your work for you. Read through the documentation, show us what you tried and then we can comment on this.